# Why is componentDidMount the best place to fire AJAX request

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

A common use case is seen at lots of react projects that the AJAX request is  fired at `componentDidMount` hook.

I just can't wrap my head around this proposed practice , let's say we have below component where the AJAX request depends on a `prop` from `parent component` and `MyComponent` won't get properly updated with correct ajax data if a second **render action** triggered from it's parent component(**with new props**) happen.but `componentDidMount` won't get executed anyway

so I think this practice is gonna cause issue , can anyone help confirm it and justify it? or correct me if I'm wrong.

```js
export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super(...arguments);
  }
  
  async componentDidMount() {
    const data = await fireAjax(this.props.id);
    this.setState({data});
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    return (
        { data && <span>{data}</span> }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It should be [componentDidMount()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount), then use [componentWillReceiveProps()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) for the updates

Comment: I think if you need props to add in your AJAX request you then should use other React lifecycle methods

Comment: And it's not defined anywhere that React will handle it returning a promise properly, so you shouldn't make it `async`. (Or if you do, you should ensure that it never throws. Since that will end up being an unhandled rejection.)

Comment: yes , I know it and async/await is just for demonstration.

Comment: *"so I think this practice is gonna cause issue"* The React development team [disagree with you](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount): *"If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request."*

Comment: @DengZhebin: Demonstrating something you're not doing or asking about doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Thanks Boss!!  Can I understand this?  if I'm still to fire ajax from componentDidMount hook , componentWillReceiveProps hook should also be used to update prop in case of any new prop from parent component.

Answer (score 3):

You're misunderstanding the pattern.

`componentDidMount` is the correct place to do async fetching *that you want to occur when the component mounts*.  If there is some other action that ought to trigger the data fetch, then yeah, do the async call in that other location.

What you really want to look into is the entire Flux paradigm, which is a fully fleshed out data flow made for react (though it can also be used elsewhere).  There are plenty of packages that wrap that design pattern with helpful handlers, the most popular being Redux.

But no, no one is suggesting that all async calls occur in that lifecycle hook.

Comment: Much apprecaited, I have some project experiences in using redux-related techniques such as redux-saga,redux-promise,redux-thunk and aware of what flux pattern means. but for this particular question about the componentDidMount. I agree the componentDidMount really does the best and safest job to fetch asynchronous data. but when rendering happens ,ajax data may not get updated because this hook is dead already.

Comment: If you want it to update, then what is doing the updating?  Whatever action triggers the update should be what is responsible for requesting the new data.

Answer (score 0):

If you do the AJAX request before the component mounts, the component will probably render before the request completes and you still have the problem of the data not being ready.

What you should be doing is making the AJAX request in the parent component, and once the request completes, you pass the data from the AJAX request to a child component through props. Perhaps displaying something to inform the user that it's loading.

Comment: I meant if you wait for it to complete before rendering. Have edited my answer.

Comment: I can't imagine how you could "wait for it to complete before rendering" without making it synchronous. The edit makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. what if the parent component also expects a prop to complete it's ajax call? imagine there's a complicated component tree out there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean `componentDidMount`.

This method will only get called once. It does not get called again on a re-render, only if the component gets deleted and remounted.

If the component needs to regularly update using different data, you would be better moving this data fetching into its parent and passing it as a prop. You could pass a `loading` prop while the data is resolving, then pass the data when it is ready.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. what if the parent component also expects a prop(maybe from a user input) to complete it's ajax call? imagine there's a complicated component tree out there. so I think there's always a component in the component tree that must deal this situation.

Comment: You'll probably want to make your ajax call in the input handler function.

Comment: The usual approach is to depend the render of your component on its state and props. And in this case, use the https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate to fetch the data depending on the user input. After updating the state again with the fetched data, the render will show the final version of the UI for the component.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check this article: https://daveceddia.com/where-fetch-data-componentwillmount-vs-componentdidmount/ by Dave Ceddia. The idea here matches what you wrote in your code. So yes, it's one of the right ways to handle side effects in React.

Just copying/pasting here ;)

> In practice, componentDidMount is the best place to put calls to fetch data, for two reasons:
>
> Using DidMount makes it clear that data won’t be loaded until after the initial render. This reminds you to set up initial state properly, so you don’t end up with undefined state that causes errors.
>
> If you ever need to render your app on the server (SSR/isomorphic/other buzzwords), componentWillMount will actually be called twice – once on the server, and again on the client – which is probably not what you want. Putting the data loading code in componentDidMount will ensure that data is only fetched from the client.